# Codeigniter function_exists not working correctly

Tags: codeigniter

I am using php [function_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) function exist on my Welcome controller. But for some reason it keeps on throwing my show_error even though my slideshow function exists.

With in my foreach loop I get module function name from database which in the foreach loop is called `$function = $module['code'];`

> Question is: How am I able to make sure function_exists checks
>   function exists correctly?

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
    $data['content_top'] = $this->content_top();

    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}

public function content_top() {
    $data['modules'] = array();

    $modules = $this->get_module();

    foreach ($modules as $module) {

        $function = $module['code'];

        if (function_exists($function)) {

            $setting_info = array('test' => 'testing');

            if ($setting_info) {
                $data['modules'][] = $this->$function($setting_info);
            }

        } else {

            show_error('This ' . $function . ' does not exist on ' . __CLASS__ . ' controller!');

        }

    }

    return $this->load->view('content_top', $data, TRUE);
}

public function banner() {

}

public function slideshow($setting) {

    $data['test'] = $setting['test'];

    $this->load->view('module/slideshow', $data);
}

public function get_module() {
    $query = $this->db->get('modules');
    return $query->result_array();
}
}
```

Comment: Anyone may I ask why the down vote any reason would be great to know so can improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function_exists()` works on functions, but not *class methods* - these are different things. What you want is [method_exists()](https://secure.php.net/method_exists):

```
method_exists($this, $function);
```